# Growing Piel de Sapo melons stalled

Tags: vegetables, plant-care, fruits, greenhouse, melons

I am experimenting growing Piel de Sapo melon plants from seed that I saved from the supermarket. I have four plants.

It took some time but eventually I got some female flowers that pollinated and started growing the fruit. The first melon grew really quickly but stalled at around the size of a mango. The second is slightly smaller but also stalled.

[image]

I did manage to pollinate a third on the same plant and it is growing quite quickly. I also have a single melon started on another plant which is going to overtake the original which I thought was the strongest.

[image]

I suspect the first fruits have stopped growing because the energy is going to the newest fruit. However, I’m wondering what will happen to these smaller melons. Will they ripen at this small size? They certainly look more mature than the newer fruits. I don’t plan to allow any more fruits to grow on the plant that only has one as it is doing so well. It is also getting late in the season here in Scotland.

**Edit:**

Adding overall picture. The plant is around 1m in height and is grown in standard compost fed with potash and tomato fertiliser, also some tea and coffee grounds occasionally. I do not know about the ph. It is watered every day or two, and not let dry out. The greenhouse does get quite warm.

[image]

Comment: Good answer and good illustrations; if could include overall illustration of plants, approximate plant height & mature leaf size, time since germination, water amount & frequency, nutrient type & amount & frequency, and soil characteristics, could also be helpful. Thank you. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have added some further details to my question.

Comment: Very excellent and helpful additional illustration & details! And you are very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, the melon was not growing anymore because the stem to it had died. However, as I mentioned it had matured even at that size and I decided to cut it open and have a look. I was pleasantly surprised by the well developed seeds and familiar melon aroma. Although there wasn’t much flesh, it was fully ripe and had a nice taste. The other melon is still growing quite well so I am hopeful of getting a bigger fruit in a few weeks.

I hope this is helpful to others experimenting growing melons, even in Scotland!

[image]

[image]